# replace arrow with plotshape with text

Tags: pine-script

I have this script that adds an arrow when moving averages cross over but would like to display label up/ label down instead.

```
    study(title="MA 5/10 Strategy", shorttitle="MA Strategy 5/10", overlay=true)
exponential = input(true, title="Exponential MA")

src = close

ma5 = exponential ? ema(src, 5) : sma(src, 5)
ma10 = exponential ? ema(src, 10) : sma(src, 10)

buy_cond = cross(ma5, ma10) and ma5 > ma10
sell_cond = cross(ma5, ma10) and ma5 < ma10

plotarrow(buy_cond ? 1 : 0, colordown=lime, maxheight=25, minheight=15)
plotarrow(sell_cond ? -1 : 0, colorup=red, maxheight=25, minheight=15)

plot( ma5, color=green, style=line, title="5", linewidth=1)
plot( ma10, color=red, style=line, title="10", linewidth=1)

alertcondition(buy_cond, title = "Go Long", message = "Go Long")
alertcondition(sell_cond, title = "Go Short", message = "Go Short")
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Replacing plotarrow with plotshape but no luck. I don’t really code much and never in pinescript I’ve just been trying to google for a solution but can’t find one.